# Defining destructor in derived class requires copy assignment operator

Tags: c++, destructor, move-semantics

Take a look at this code example:

```
class A {
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A &operator=(const A&) = delete;    
protected:
    A() { }
    virtual ~A() { } // required for inheritance
    A(A&&) = default;
    A &operator=(A&&) = default;
};

struct B : public A {
    ~B() { } // Without the destructor the code compiles
};

int main(void)
{
    B b = B();
}
```

This code fails to compile, wtih `g++-9` telling me that (in short)

> line 15: error: use of deleted function 'B::B(const B&)' 
>   line 9: note: 'B::B(const B&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed: 
>   line 9: error: use of deleted function 'A::A(A&)'

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dVUxNt) for the full error message.

Why does the compiler not use the move constructor/move assignment operator from `class A`? If I remove the destructor defined in `struct B` the code compiles. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: `A(A&)` should be `A(const A&)`, and `operator=(A&)` should be `operator=(const A&)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
~B() { }
```

in `B` you stop the compiler from generating a move constructor, so all it has is a copy constructor.  Since `A`'s is not acceptable it can't compile.

When you remove it, the compiler can create the move constructor automatically and you're good to go.

---

Note that this only applies to pre C++17.  With C++17's guaranteed copy elision, `B b = B();` becomes `B b();` (if that would actually compile) so no copy or move happens.

Comment: If I now add the default move assignment operator (by using `= default`) will this move constructor call the one defined (manually or by default) in `A` to move the `A`-part of the object?

Comment: @HerpDerpington Yep.  It's one of the reasons it was added to the language.

Comment: So by adding a destructor it is now compelled to generate the other operations that would normally be defaulted?

Comment: @wcochran No, adding a non-default destructor stops the automatic move constructor and move assignment operator from being generated,

Comment: @NathanOliver That's somehow really counter-intuitive

Comment: @NathanOliver Are you sure that the ones defined in `A` will be called? It does not seem like it; or did I miss something? https://godbolt.org/z/P6CQ9J

Comment: @HerpDerpington Think about it this way, if you define a destructor, there must be a reason, and if there is, a default move constructor might do the wrong thing.  So, instead of automatically generating a potential bug, the rules say don't generate the move operations.  Think about a C++03 string class.  The default move constructor wouldn't swap the pointer, it would make a copy, which would be very bad as you'll get a double delete.

Comment: @HerpDerpington Unfortunately you are the victim of optimization there.  The copy is beiling elided and no move or copy happens.  If you turn that off, you can see it print `x` here: https://godbolt.org/z/m-S_-t

Comment: Yep, saw that. Used a different approach: https://godbolt.org/z/d-apX3 (Of course, there is no actual move of the fields here)